# If a compact subset is contained in an open subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$, is a small cylinder of this compact subset also contained in the open set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $O\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set, $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ a compact set and $a\in \mathbb{R}$, such that $$\{a\}\times K\subseteq O$$ holds.

Does there exist an $\epsilon>0$, such that $$(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\times K\subseteq O$$ is true?

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! Have you thought about the problem? What have you tried, or where did you get stuck?

Comment: Yes, I have. I tried to construct a counterexample, but it did not work out.

Comment: The cylinder $C$ is a closed subset of a compact set you chosen say that $X$, so it is compact, and since there is an open subset $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ containing $X$ then $C\subset X\subset U$.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid excessive typing, assume without loss of generality, that $a=0$. For each point $x\in K$, fix a neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ and an $\epsilon_x>0$ such that $(-\epsilon_x,\epsilon_x)\times U_x\subseteq O$. Such $U_x$ and $\epsilon_x$ exist because $O$ is open and contains $(x,0)$.  By compactness, finitely many of the $U_x$'s cover $K$; say these are $U_{x_1},\dots,U_{x_n}$.  Let $\epsilon$ be the smallest of the corresponding $\epsilon_{x_1},\dots,\epsilon_{x_n}$. Because this is the minimum of only finitely many positive numbers, $\epsilon$ is positive.  For each $(t,y)\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times K$, we have an $x_i$ such that $y\in U_{x_i}$ and therefore $(t,y)\in (-\epsilon_{x_i},\epsilon_{x_i})\times U_{x_i}\subseteq O$.

Comment: Thank you, this works just fine! The strategy seems to fail in the "relative" situation to which I tried to adapt it. The situation I have in mind is the following: Suppose we have a closed set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $O$ is open in $A$ not necessarily in whole $\mathbb{R}^n$. Furthermore it holds $(\{0\}\times K)\cap A\subseteq O$. Can we conclude the existence of an $\epsilon>0$, such that $((-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\times K)\cap A\subseteq O$? However I was not able to cook up a counterexample. Do you have an idea or does the claim remain true?

Comment: @user263827: If you have a followup question, it is best to pose it as a new question (include a link to this old question, to explain the motivation). That way, you give your potential answerers the opportunity to get reputation for answering the followup question.

Comment: @user263827: Also, if you like the answer to your question, as your comment indicates that you do, it is customary to select the one that you like best.